# Python Scrapy XPATH chain selector different result

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

**Problem:**
I am trying to use xpath selector chain for select certain element with scrapy, but I found the result of my chain is different from doing it in one selector, I want to understand why this situation happens.

when I execute in **one selector** below, i got nothing (this is what i want, i want only the fachinformatio under praeparat part):

```
response.xpath("//div[@id='praeparat']//a[contains(@href, 'fachinformatio')]")
```

when I execute in **two selector**, i got something which is not from the preparation but the whole html:

```
content = response.css("div.content")
preparation = content.css("div[id='praeparat']")
preparation.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "fachinformation")]')
```

I do not understand why there is a difference between this two.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the second xpath should start with a dot i.e. `.//a...`

Comment: @tomjn thank you, it works. does it mean if i am chaining xpath or css selector, i should always starts with a dot when it is not the first level ? if I don't add this dot, it looks for the entire html regardless what i chained before ?

Comment: Yes the . means relative to the previous selection, otherwise it will query the entire html

Comment: In fact, the abbreviated form `//` traverse the document tree from the root node. The abreviated form `.` expand to `self::node()` but which will be it depends entirely on your XPath engine API and whats's the context node for each invocation.